# Unable to search by custom field in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I use Hibernate Search 5.5.7 (current stable) and I need to search by OffsetDateTime parts (hours and minutes), but without date. 
I saw [such solution](http://%20https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/engine/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/test/dsl/NumericTypeGuessedTest.java).
 My bridge:

```
public class OrderDeliveryTimeBridge implements 
              MetadataProvidingFieldBridge, ParameterizedBridge {

public static final String INTERVAL_BOUND_PROPERTY_NAME = "intervalBound";

public static final String INTERVAL_BOUND_START = "start";

public static final String INTERVAL_BOUND_END = "end";

public static final String BCD_TIME_SUFFIX = "_BCDTime";

public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_START = INTERVAL_BOUND_START + BCD_TIME_SUFFIX;

public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_END = INTERVAL_BOUND_END + BCD_TIME_SUFFIX;

private String intervalBound;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderDeliveryTimeBridge.class);

@Override
public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
    builder.field(getPropertyName(), FieldType.INTEGER);
    builder.field(name, FieldType.STRING);
}

@Override
public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
    log.info("Set called for {}", name);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = (OffsetDateTime) value;
    Integer fieldValue = dateTime.getHour() * 100 + dateTime.getMinute();

    log.info("Add field '{}' with value '{}'", getPropertyName(), fieldValue);
    luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(getPropertyName(), fieldValue, document);

    IntField field = new IntField(getPropertyName(), fieldValue, Field.Store.NO);
    document.add(field);
}

private String getPropertyName() {
    if (intervalBound.equals(INTERVAL_BOUND_START))
        return PROPERTY_NAME_START;
    else return PROPERTY_NAME_END;
}

@Override
public void setParameterValues(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    String bound = parameters.get(INTERVAL_BOUND_PROPERTY_NAME);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(bound))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The parameter 'INTERVAL_BOUND_PROPERTY_NAME' are required!");
    if (!bound.equals(INTERVAL_BOUND_START) && !bound.equals(INTERVAL_BOUND_END))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value for parameter 'INTERVAL_BOUND_PROPERTY_NAME'");
    intervalBound = bound;
}
}
```

Mapping of property:

```
@Field(store = Store.YES, bridge =
@FieldBridge(impl = OrderDeliveryTimeBridge.class,
        params = @Parameter(name = OrderDeliveryTimeBridge.INTERVAL_BOUND_PROPERTY_NAME,
                value = OrderDeliveryTimeBridge.INTERVAL_BOUND_START)
))
private OffsetDateTime desiredDeliveryIntervalStart;
```

Try to search:

```
queryBuilder.keyword().onField(OrderDeliveryTimeBridge.PROPERTY_NAME_START).matching(820).createQuery()
```

but I've a Exception: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field start_BCDTime in

Where is a bug? Help, please!

Comment: Just so you know, Hibernate Search 5.5.7 is absolutely not the current stable. It's 5.7.2. See http://hibernate.org/search/downloads/.

Comment: Please provide the full code for when you're building your query and the full stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake. Hibernate Search version is  5.7.1.Final